# Flutter: Image Package copyCropCircle() not cropping

Tags: android, flutter, image, dart, mobile

First post here.

I am attempting to crop an image to a circle on the press of a button, and store it on my database.

The image itself is captured from the camera and successfully being manipulated to be cropped into a square shape before cropping to a circle; however, when it comes to copyCropCircle(), nothing is changing.

The image is also successfully storing on my database, in a square cropped form. Anyone have experience with copyCropCircle?

Thanks!

Below is my code for the button that performs this operation:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  // Load the image file into memory
  img.Image cropImage = img.decodeImage(File(globals.filepath).readAsBytesSync())!;
  // Crop and convert the image to a circle.
  //cropImage = img.copyResize(cropImage, width: 200, height: 200);
  cropImage = img.copyCropCircle(cropImage,);

  /// Successfully creates cropped... square?
  // Save circularImage as a temporary file
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory(); // get temporary directory
  final tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/circular_image.png'); // create temporary file
  tempFile.writeAsBytesSync(img.encodePng(cropImage)); // write image bytes to file

  // Upload the image to storage as bytes and get the url
  String cropImageUrl = await DatabaseService.uploadImage(tempFile.path);
  print(cropImageUrl);

  // Delete the temporary file
  tempFile.deleteSync();
},
```

There was another post very similar to this; however, I cannot comment without 50 reputation, and whatever example they have does not solve my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I am unsure if it is deprecated, but copyCropCircle was returning regular cropped squares no matter how I tweaked it. Turns out copyCrop has a radius property. Using this allowed me to crop the image into a circle; however, this still returns a square shape with a black background and a circle crop of the image as the center/foreground. So while it's progress, the issue is unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the images I was calling copyCropCircle on had only 3 channels, so alpha was never getting set. To fix it, I had to check for the existence of an alpha channel and create a new image using the 'convert' method.

```
if (!origImage.hasAlpha) {
    origImage =
              origImage.convert(format: origImage.format, numChannels: 4);
}
```